# Unknown column 'factura0_.id_coche' in 'field list'

Tags: java, rest, api

I'm trying to retrieve all the "facturas" that have one "coche". I made onetomany relationship because each "factura" have his own "idCoche" in the database.  I've been looking for resolve this error but none post help me. 
I have these entities:

FACTURA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "factura")
public class Factura implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "imagenFactura")
private byte[] imagenFactura;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idCoche")
private Coche coche;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public byte[] getImagenFactura() {
    return imagenFactura;
}

public void setImagenFactura(byte[] imagenFactura) {
    this.imagenFactura = imagenFactura;
}

public Coche getCoche() {
    return coche;
}

public void setCoche(Coche coche) {
    this.coche = coche;
} 
}
```

COCHE:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "coche")
public class Coche implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "matricula")
private String matricula;

@Column(name = "marca")
private String marca;

@Column(name = "modelo")
private String modelo;

@Column(name = "titular")
private String titular;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="coche")
private List<Factura> facturas;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}

public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getModelo() {
    return modelo;
}

public void setModelo(String modelo) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
}

public String getTitular() {
    return titular;
}

public void setTitular(String titular) {
    this.titular = titular;
}

public List<Factura> getFacturas() {
    return facturas;
}

public void setFacturas(List<Factura> facturas) {
    this.facturas = facturas;
}
}
```

This is my JPA repository

```
@Repository
public interface FacturaRepository extends JpaRepository<Factura, Long> {

    List<Factura> findByCocheId(Long id);


}
```

And, finally, this is my resource (Which generates the exception when calling the repository method):

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Factura>> getAllFacturas(@PathVariable Long id) {
    List<Factura> facturas = facturaRepository.findByCocheId(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(facturas, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify the relation in `Factura` like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", 
      referencedColumnName = "id")
private Coche coche;
```

Comment: The name of the id in the table is "id". IdCoche is the name of the foreign key in the table Factura

Comment: In `JoinColumn` you should put the name of the column in the other entity, not the current one. So try putting `id` instead of `idCoche`.

Comment: I tried `@JoinColumn(name="id")
          private Coche coche;` and I'm getting this error: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.padre.taxis.domain.Factura column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: @Dzfecko I guess it happens because you have the same name `id` for the id in both tables. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I tried that too. I think I'm going to give up haha. Thanks you for your time.